# Laravel public folder path

Tags: php, laravel, web, hosting

I am using laravel 10, and have images inside /public/images , when i try yo use asset or public_path(), i get a duplicate prepended to the url like so

**Using public_path();**
file_get_contents(/var/www/soccia/var/www/soccia/public): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory.

**Using asset();**
file_get_contents(/var/www/socciahttp://158.68.112.29/images/1705750845_profile.png): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory

database contains paths like this (/images/img.png)

i did change asset_url in app.php

'asset_url' => env('ASSET_URL', null),

but doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: in env has a ASSET_URL?

Comment: no, env doesn't have ASSET_URL

Answer (score 1):

You can try `url($filepath)`

For example, if a register to a filepath on your database is `images/1705750845_profile.png` and you need the path to this image in your public folder, you can use `url('images/1705750845_profile.png')`. The result will be (on a local development env):

```
http://localhost/images/1705750845_profile.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `public_path('images');` instead of `public_path();`?

Comment: for example:

$image = $request->file('image');
$imageName = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension(),
$image->save(public_path('images/' . $imageName));

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).